# C# rotate arrow with wind

Tags: c#

I'm trying to rotate an arrow and place it inside a compass image to indicate the wind direction. First I was using a dot and it was working but now with the arrow it some times point to the wrong direction. Here is the code I'm using to rotate the image and place it around a circle. The problem is with the image rotation.

The problem is, the back image is static, a circle with the degrees written on it, I used to just place a dot in the wind degree, but now I would like to put and arrow over the edge of the circle indicating the direction that par I'm using the code `Bitmap imagemrodada = rotateImage(newSeta, wind_degrees + 90);` but the arrow is not pointing to the direction I want, here in this link there is an example with the same wind direction I'm trying to do. http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/03772.html

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(wind_kph) > 0)
{
    Image image1 = Image.FromFile(arquivo_display);
    Image image2 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\red\Desktop\arrow-06.png");
    Bitmap newPonto = (Bitmap) new Bitmap(image1);
    Bitmap newSeta = (Bitmap) new Bitmap(image2);
    image1.Dispose();
    image1 = null;
    image2.Dispose();
    image2 = null;
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newPonto))
    {
        Double distanceFromCenter = 45;
        Bitmap imagemrodada = rotateImage(newSeta, wind_degrees + 90);
        Console.WriteLine(wind_degrees + 90);
        Double angleInDegrees = wind_degrees - 90;
        Double angleAsRadians = (angleInDegrees*Math.PI)/180.0;
        Double centerX = 95;
        Double centerY = 95;
        Double x = centerX + Math.Cos(angleAsRadians)*distanceFromCenter;
        Double y = centerY + Math.Sin(angleAsRadians)*distanceFromCenter;
        g.DrawImageUnscaled(imagemrodada, Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y));
        newPonto.Save(arquivo_display);
        newPonto.Dispose();
        newPonto = null;
        newSeta.Dispose();
        newSeta = null;
       }
```

Comment: Whoever is downvoting, please explain.This guy provided code.

Comment: Your code lacks comments to explain what you are doing at each step. It would also be nice to have the variable names in English.

Comment: He didn't provide a clear explanation of what's not working.

Comment: You mentioned that "it used to work with a dot" and your code looks like it's calculating that dot's position. the math.cos and math.sin functions are the well known method of getting x and y coordinates from angle + distance. But you don't need any of that if you are drawing a rotated image! you need to rotate the image around it's center and draw it at the exact center of the compass. the image's x and y need to be fixed, only the rotation of the image is effected by the wind direction. Post more details if you want a full answer to your problem.

Comment: Added more info to the question

Comment: If the problem is with the rotation, let us see the `rotateImage` method's source and what your image looks like